# Node.JS + MySQL - Condensing 40+ UPDATE statements into just one with unique WHERE clauses in each one

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sql-update

I'm trying to make a cooldown system that involves a MySQL database to store the "remaining time" in the cooldown. I currently have about 50 cooldowns to manage, updating the DB every second. Yes, I need that 1-second accuracy and no I can't use vars because the data needs to survive app restarts. So here's my code:

```
function cooldowns() {
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col1 = col1 - 1 WHERE col1 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col2 = col2 - 1 WHERE col2 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col3 = col3 - 1 WHERE col3 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col4 = col4 - 1 WHERE col4 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col5 = col5 - 1 WHERE col5 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col6 = col6 - 1 WHERE col6 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col7 = col7 - 1 WHERE col7 > 0")
  connection.query("UPDATE users SET col8 = col8 - 1 WHERE col8 > 0")
}
```

I have those lines and about 40-50 of them... All for different columns. Now I know that I can do something along the lines of `UPDATE users SET col1 = asd, col2 = asdf, etc` but the issue is the `WHERE` clause being unique to each query. How can I condense all of this down to just one query? Note that the table name is the same throughout the function but the columns and `WHERE` clauses are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current scenario it would seem that running multiple queries is your only option.

However, from your example it looks like all the columns being updated here are numeric, and conditions are to ensure that the values don't fall below zero.

If that's the only constraint you are looking for, you could follow a different approach. Alter your schema a bit to change the data type of each column from `Int` to `Int UNSIGNED`. That would automatically ensure that values don't fall below zero. Assigning a negative value to such column would store zero instead.

Now with your new schema in place, you could run single query like:

```
function cooldowns() {
    connection.query("UPDATE users SET col1 = col1 - 1, col2 = col2 - 1, col3 = col3 -1 ...");
}
```

The where clause can completely be skipped, or amended to other necessary criteria for selecting the rows.

Comment: This seems to be working but another quick question - How can I make MySQL ignore an operation when the number is updated to try to be below 0? Something such as what an `INSERT IGNORE` would do with primary keys